# Trying to find the right materialized view refresh options

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a lot of historical tables and to help with the queries I created materialized view. Right now I do

```
create materialized view ...
refresh force on demand
```

And have a job once a day that does

```
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(..., 'C')
```

Is there a way for the materialized view to be updated dynamically without being to slow? **The changes only adds to the materialized view, they never update or delete the data.** I have a bit of trouble understanding all the refresh options.

Answer (score 1):

Use of fast refresh, with materialized view logs on the source tables, should work for you. It would allow you to only apply changes to the MV. Check out this article on MV options and architecture for more details: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views